# Почему в методе можно изменять массив без передавания его по ссылке?

Tags: c#, массивы, классы, функции

Имеются в C# такие функции как

```
Array.Copy(source2,2,target,3,2);
source.CopyTo(target,0);
```

Их документация гласит следующее

> ```
> public static void Copy(Array sourceArray, long sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, long destinationIndex, long length);
> ```
>
> Копирует диапазон элементов из массива System.Array, начиная с заданного индекса источника, и вставляет его в другой массив System.Array, начиная с заданного индекса назначения. Длина и индексы задаются как 32-битовые целые числа.

Во 2 случае аналогично:

> ```
> public void CopyTo(Array array, int index);
> ```
>
> Копирует все элементы текущего одномерного массива в заданный одномерный массив
>   начиная с указанного индекса в массиве назначения.Индекс задается как 32-битовое
>   целое число.

Их вызов:

```
Array.Copy(source,2,target,2,2);
source.CopyTo(target,0);
```

Однако суть не в этом все эти методы возвращают Void и изменяют содержимое одного из аргументов однако в документации что то это не показано ведь как правило если я правильно понимаю здесь должно быть по правилам быть так:

```
Array.Copy(source,2,ref target,2,2);//передача по ссылке
source.CopyTo(ref target,0);//передача по ссылке
```

**Почему это не отражается в коде** по какому правилу изменяет содержимое target без ссылки

Comment: Это ведь не расширение а метод

Comment: Массив - ссылочный тип, потому он всегда передается по ссылке. Или я не понял вопроса

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ничто не мешает изменять изменять *элементы* переданного массива. Они являются частью объекта массива и доступны через переданную в метод ссылку. Т.к. сама ссылка не изменяется, то передавать ее по ссылке (`ref`) не нужно.

Например такой метод успешно изменит первый элемент массива:

```
void Change(int[] array) 
{
    //изменяем элемент массива, можно без ref
    array[0] = 1;
}
```

### Использование `ref`

`ref` позволяет изменить *объект массива*, на который ссылается переменная `target`.
Массив — ссылочный тип, соответственно в метод передается ссылка на массив. Ссылка по-умолчанию передается по значению и изменения ссылки не влияют на переданное значение. Для того чтобы сама ссылка передавалась по ссылке Вам понадобится `ref`.

Рассмотрим два метода (с `ref` и без):

```
void ReasssignIncorrectly(int[] array) 
{
    //пересоздание массива, т.к. аргумент не ref, это не окажет влияния на переданную ссылку
    array = new[]{2};
}

void ReasssignCorrectly(ref int[] array) 
{
    //пересоздается успешно, т.к. ref
    array = new[]{3};
}
```

`ReasssignIncorrectly` не окажет влияния на переданную переменную.

Наример, такой код:

```
var a = new int[1];
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
Change(a);
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
//не изменит массив
ReasssignIncorrectly(a);
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
ReasssignCorrectly(ref a);
Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
```

Выведет

```
0
1
1
3
```

Демонстрация на Ideone: https://ideone.com/Gxz1rq

Comment: Хм, я думал, что у автора вопрос о изменении содержимого массива,  а не ссылки на сам массив. Но вам все равно плюс :)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за плюс! Про изменение я тоже написал, но как я понял наибольший диссонанс вызывает именно (не-)использование ref и посчитал нужным разъяснить.

Comment: Да не знал этого ваще капец неожиданно! Читаю книгу C# 4.0 Герберта Шилдта и такой момент упустил (уже 700 страниц прочел)